Opposite of a Dedekind cut
I'm reading the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ using Dedekind cuts on $\mathbb{Q}$. In my course note, a cut is a nonempty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying:

if $x \in A$ and $y \leq x$ then $y \in A$

Sum of two cuts $A$ and $B$ is defined by:$$A+B = \{x + y, \; x \in A , \, y \in B \}$$The opposition $-A$ of a cut $A$ is defined by$$-A = \{ y, \; y \leq -x \; \forall x \in A \} $$ and the zero cut is $0 = \{ x \leq 0\}$.
Then the note says "it is easy to verify that $A + (-A) = 0$" (on verifie facilement que...) After trying for a while, I still cannot prove this fact:

in the one hand $A + (-A) \subseteq 0$, indeed if $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ then $y \leq -x$, so $x+y \leq 0$
in the other hand, how to show that $0 \subseteq A + (-A)$?

Thanks for any hint.

That is not a complete definition of a one-sided Dedekind cut; see here for some additional conditions you need. In particular the set should be upwards open, so $0$ is instead ${x < 0}$, which makes the reverse inclusion possible to prove.

This is only true when $A$ is a rational cut: suppose $0 \in A + (-A)$. Hence there is $a \in A$ such that $-a \in -A$, hence $\forall b \in A$, $-a \leq -b$, hence $b \leq a$. So $a$ is a maximal element of $A$, hence $A$ represents the rational number $a$.
As stated in my comment, one needs to be more careful about the definition of a Dedekind cut.
